# Does browser continue to send requests for resource even with `Cache-Control: max-age`

Tags: javascript, caching

I'm reading [this great article](https://www.mnot.net/cache_docs/) on caching and there is the following there:

> Validators are very important; if one isn’t present, and there isn’t
>   any freshness information (Expires or Cache-Control) available, caches
>   will not store a representation at all.
>
> The most common validator is the time that the document last changed,
>   as communicated in Last-Modified header. When a cache has a
>   representation stored that includes a Last-Modified header, it can use
>   it **to ask the server if the representation has changed since the last
>   time it was seen**, with an If-Modified-Since request.

So, I'm wondering whether browser continues to send requests (for example HEAD) for a resource even if I specified `Cache-Control: max-age=3600`? If it doesn't, than what's the point in this header? Is it used after the `max-age` time passes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Cache-Control: max-age=3600` header means that the browser will cache the response for up to 3600 seconds. After that time has passed it may no longer serve the response without first confirming that it is still fresh.

In order to this, the browser can either:

- Fetch the full resource with a normal `GET` request (transfers the whole response body again)
- Or perform a revalidation based on an **ETag** (`If-None-Match`) or the **Last-Modified** header (`If-Modified-Since`), i.e. the client only fetches the response body if it has actually changed. This is of course only possible if the validator was present in the original response.

**In short**: the reason to use both `max-age` and a cache validator is to first cache the response for some time and then perform a bandwidth-saving revalidation to confirm the resource's freshness.

Comment: thanks, it's a bit different with ETag, because with `ETag` it sends always sends but the response is usually 304 Not Modified. So with `Cache-Control` no response will be sent at all during 3600, correct?

Comment: With both methods no request/response will be sent during the 3600 seconds. The 304 is sent when the resource is not modified, irrespective of whether the client sent an Etag oder the Last-Modified date for validation. Most servers can be configured to use an ETag (usually a content hash) or a Last-Modified header (extracted from the file system metadata) to automatically allow this lightweight 304 revalidation. I recommend using ETags over dates, since the second-level-resolution of the header cannot detect multiple changes within one second.